# VBA workbook open does not run after enable content prompt

Tags: vba, excel

I have a situation where I save a macro-enabled workbook to a untrusted folder (like my users will probably do). When I open the file from Excel (most recent list or File > Open), the file opens and I get the warning banner and click Enable Content. I have a "Hello World" msgBox at the top of the Workbook_Open routine, but the message (and hence the rest of the code) does not appear.

If I close and restart Excel, then open the file, the Workbook_Open event runs.

Any ideas how to solve this? Having users set up trusted locations on multiple folders they might be saving to is not a good solution, nor is requiring them to shutdown and restart Excel workable either.

Thanks, folks!

Comment: Generally speaking security settings can't be bypassed with VBA. THis is for very good reason and (obviously) by design. You might consider a bypass method to alert the users of what manual steps must be taken: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16599

Comment: I think you're saying that if the file is opened from within an active session of Excel, despite clicking "Enable Content", the content is not enabled - and the `Workbook_Open` event doesn't fire?  But if Excel has nothing else open the event fires?

Comment: A [digital signature](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s240/digital_certificates_for_macros.htm) (of the VBA code) that is trusted by the users might help here

Comment: It isn't that you need to close and restart Excel. You have to save the workbook to your disc after enabling content. Next time you open the workbook the banner will not appear and the Open event will fire.

Comment: David, I'm not trying to bypass security. Only trying to get the Workbook_Open routine to run after the user has closed the file, re-opens it (in the same Excel instance) and clicks "Enable Content".

Comment: CLR, A macro attached to a button on a worksheet saves the file (as macro-enabled XSLM) then saves another file (with a -L suffix) with all the cells locked as a normal non-macro-enabled (XLSX). Then closes the file. The user goes to the most-recent-used list or clicks the macro-enabled file just saved, the active content warning banner shows up, they click Enable Content, but the Workbook_Open event does not run, nor will any other worksheet events or button-activated code. It's as if macros are disabled even though they clicked Enable Content.fine.

Comment: If they completely close Excel and start Excel again and repeat the open/Enable Content, the Workbook_Open and all other macros work

Comment: Peh, I didn't want to go with a digital signature since a personal signature seems to only apply to your computer and doesn't help when the macro-enabled file is sent to others, unless you opt to pay for a public signature, which is costly. Plus, the idea is to make this easy for non-technical users to work with without jumping through hoops.

Comment: I should add that users do have their trust setting set to "Disable macros with notification" which should allow macros to run (including Workbook_Open) when they open a file and click Enable Content. But the macros don't work unless they close/restart Excel and re-open the saved macro-enabled file.

Comment: *A macro attached to a button on a worksheet saves the file (as macro-enabled XSLM)* -- Show the code for this button?

Comment: Also NB the order of events and as those pertain to this scenario: the workbook is *already open*, and enabling content does not re-trigger the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: David, here's a link to the code: [link](http://www.rnbow.com/code)

Answer (score 0):

Copypasta:

https://excelribbon.tips.net/T012873_Always_Opening_a_Workbook_that_is_Editable.html

If you are actually wanting to make sure that the real "Protected View" is turned off, that is a different story. The settings for Protected View are controlled on a system-by-system basis in the Trust Center. You can see the settings by following these steps:

1. Display the Developer tab of the ribbon.
2. Click Macro Security in the Code group.
3. Excel displays the Trust Center dialog box. At the left side of the
   dialog box click Protected View. (See Figure 1.)

[image]

*Figure 1. The Trust Center dialog box.*

The actual Protection View settings available depend on the version of Excel you are using. As mentioned, these settings are controlled at a system level; they are not handled on a workbook-by-workbook basis. The upshot is that they cannot be circumvented by macro code. If they could, then it would render a system completely vulnerable to whatever code was in a workbook being opened—we would be back to the days of macro viruses that were common with some earlier versions of Office products.

Additional information on how the Protected View settings operate can be found on this Microsoft web site:

> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx

Whether a workbook opens in Protected View or not depends on a user's system settings. This means that control of what opens is entirely up to the individual user and cannot be "forced" by a workbook author. There are ways, though, that the impact of this can be mitigated, and they have to do with trust. Note that at the left of the Trust Center dialog box there are three settings that control this relative to workbooks:

- **Trusted Publishers.** Workbooks from whatever publishers are listed in this area are trusted and will open directly, bypassing Protected View.
- **Trusted Locations.** Workbooks stored in the locations listed in this area are trusted and will open directly, bypassing Protected View.
- **Trusted Documents.** Individual workbooks noted in tis area are trusted and will open directly, bypassing Protected View.

For your workbook, then, to bypass Protected View, you need to be a trusted publisher, the workbook needs to be stored in a trusted location, or it needs to be noted on the system as a trusted document. All of these settings are, again, under control of the user and cannot be modified through macro code.

Comment: David, thanks for a lot of good information, but I'm not trying to use Protected Mode, nor do I want users to have to jump through hoops setting this or trusted locations.

Comment: The simple matter is that macros don't work after re-opening a saved macro-enabled file (in the same instance from which is was saved) and clicking the Enable Content button, but they do run when the user closes/restarts Excel and then re-opens/Enables Content.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the issue, David and Peh's answers and comments here are all relevant and correct. Signing and altering your trust settings **will** resolve this. I wanted to add this as a comment, but it's too long.

However, if you're wondering ***why*** Excel is inviting you to `[Enable Content]`, but then *doesn't* enable macros on request (how I read your question) then I'd wonder that too. If there were settings that disallowed the macros to run, it would/should not offer enabling to you.

If you recreate the issue, and click `[Enable Content]`, can you manually run a macro by switching to the VBE editor and clicking F5/F8? I suspect not. I suspect that when you're clicking `[Enable Content]`, Excel is not inviting enabling Macros at all, but instead perhaps Data connections or something similar.

Comment: Hi CLR, You are correct. Wondering why Excel invites to Enable Content, but then doesn't enable macros. If users re-open the saved macro-enabled file in the same instance of Excel, they see the active content warning banner, click Enable Macros, but the Workbook_Open macro nor any others work. If they close Excel and then open/Enable, all the macros run as expected. To answer your other question, if I open the saved macro-enabled file in the same instance it was saved in, Enable Content, macros don't run, but if I switch to VBE, I AM able to run macros...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a solution to the problem. I added Application.EnableEvents = True before the code saves both versions of the file and also before closing the open file. It seems as if the file is saved with events disabled, the events won't be enabled when re-opened in the same instance of Excel. I would have thought that events are always re-enabled upon open, but didn't seem to be so in my case. Thanks all for your replies and time!